# getJSON on wamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, wamp

I have a json file in my wamp www directory

```
[
  { "c" : 2344},
  { "c" : 5433}
]
```

In my html page also in the wamp directory i have a getJSON call

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/test.json", function(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

This `getJSON` does not do anything, no errors, nothing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're also missing a closing paren `)` on `getJSON` method

Comment: So sorry how do i close a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works good for me:

json file:

```
[
  {"c":2244} ,
  {"c":3344}
]
```

javascript:

```
$.getJSON ('test.json', function (data) {
   console.log (data); // prints [object, object] with object.c = 2244 and object.c = 3344
});
```

test.json is in the same folder of the javascript file directory.

Ciao

Comment: Don't worry: you can leave the question opened. People can see that the parenthesis are very important and your json were well formed :P

Answer (score 0):

build a php file that give JSON output.

in order to achieve it build a php array, pass this array to `json_encode`, and echo the output.

Then query the php file with the `getJSON` function

Answer (score 0):

```
[
  { "c" : 2344},
  { "c" : 5433}
]
```

this is not a valid json, you should change it like this,

```
{
 "list" : [
     { "c" : 2344},
     { "c" : 5433} 
  ]
}

$.getJSON("http://localhost/test.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data.list.length); // 2
    console.log(data.list[0].c); // 2344
    console.log(data.list[1].c); // 5433

    for(var d in data.list) {
        alert(data.list[d].c); // alert("2344"), alert("5433")
    }
```

​
    }

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>getJSON Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$.getJSON("http://localhost/test.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        alert(key+" : "+value);
    });
});

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
I'm Good.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Jed Your json is not formatted correctly. try: {"c":2344,"d":5433}